# Regular expression to delete text between tags

Tags: regex

I'm translating a document in a CAT software and I'm having trouble dealing with a heavily tagged document. The software supports regular expressions and I'm hoping that one can be created to help me with this problem. I'd need a regular expression that selects everything between the cursor insertion point up to the "less than" symbol <, which marks the beggining of a tag. That would allow me to start typing immediatelly, replacing the original text with my translation. 
And then I'd need another expression to jump the tag, that is, to place the cursor right after the last "greater than" symbol, which can be identified as the one that is not followed with the "less than" symbol. In other words, the regular expression would command moving the cursor to the position right after the "greater than" > symbol followed by anything other than the "less than" < symbol. 
Here's an example:

```
> Some student will investigate two dialects of </s1></s0><s2><s3>every
> </s3></s2><s4><s5>language </s5></s4>
```

The insertion point is at the beginning of the sentence, right before the word "Some" and I need a regex that will select all the text up to the "less than" < symbol, that is, after the word "of". At this point I'd need a regex that would jump the insertion point right before the word "every".

Comment: Can you load the text into a texteditor (supporting regex, e.g. `Notepad++`) before translating. Then it's simply a matter to replace `<[^>]+>` with an empty string. [Like this.](https://regex101.com/r/aD9yM2/1).

Comment: Thank you vp_arth, since I'm not a programmer I can't be sure, but though it may look similar to my question, it asks for a different thing to be done with a regular expression. Also, the answers on the other thread suggest that using regular expressions with HTML files is not possible, and I'm not sure if the same applies for XML files, which I need a regular expression to apply to. Hopefully, someone gives me a definitive answer to my question and someone clears this out to me.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ClasG. I can't do that, the whole point with using CAT software is to keep the tags in place and translate the text in between them. That way the formatting of the original document remains intact.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting up to the next tag can be done with

```
[^<]*
```

Then it's a bit unclear if the second regex - *skip the tag* - should simply match the tag. Then it's

```
<[^>]*>
```

If it should the select the next text, it's more complicated. But let's start with this ;).

Comment: Thank you for the help TEXHIK and ClasG. Your first expression ClasG does the first half of the job, it does select everything up to the "less than" symbol, and that will do when I select from the beginning of the sentence up to < symbol. @TEXHIK, your expression does exactly what I need but to be useful it needs to exclude zero string matches between > and <, and that way I'm skipping tags. It needs to match only strings that have any number of whatever characters between ><

Answer (score 0):

`[^>]*(?=<)`
Will find all text between `>` and `<`. However, it will *find* and *select* the result, not place a cursor somewhere.